# How to create responsive columns

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I noticed that on Wikipedia, the notes in the Notes section are displayed in columns and the number of columns is automatically adapted to the screen size. Exemple: [Wikipedia's article on Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science).

I want to replicate the same thing. Is there some simple way to achieve this, perhaps with jQuery?

Comment: Do you specifically want to do this with jQuery, because i think it will be easier with things like CSS3 and Bootstrap added to it.

Comment: I had thought jQuery would be the easiest option but it doesn't have to be specifically jQuery. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve multiple columns that adjust with the width of a screen. I would suggest you take a look at CSS media queries and CSS3 multiple columns.

You can read up on how to adjust the style on the basis of screen size here: 
http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

You can read up on creating multiple column divs in css3 here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp

In order to completely understand and grasp the concept of responsive design, I highly recommend the following book/e-book:
http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

It's cheap and a quick and easy read that has helped me quite a bit.